# Some characters are filtered in bash

Tags: bash, readline, line-editor

I'm currently running a Xubuntu image using VirtualBox and a strange issue just started occurring: I cannot enter <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd> in a terminal or terminal emulator. <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> (that is, <kbd>a</kbd>/<kbd>c</kbd> + left/right <kbd>Shift</kbd> or with Caps Lock active) work just fine, and <kbd>a</kbd>/<kbd>c</kbd> work fine in graphical applications; it's only when using the full terminal or `xfce4-terminal`/`xterm` that the keys don't work. This seems to be a user-specific thing, as I can use `a` and `c` just fine when entering the user name for login at a terminal but once logged in the keys no longer work; however, I cannot figure out what settings I changed to somehow cause it.

Additional info: the characters are also filtered when pasting text into a terminal emulator; for a moment, I was able to get `a` to paste as part of a string when it was at the front, but I'm no longer able to.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @jimmij GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: If you run `tee` in that terminal, can you type `a` and `c`?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, and I can also paste them in. This also works if I run a terminal program such as vim, etc.; it seems to be limited to the command line/shell itself.

Comment: Start `bash` with options `--noprofile --norc`, same result?

Comment: Also, I can run a bash script containing those characters just fine, so it's not like shell as a whole is rejecting them), and `sh` also allows entry of those characters from the terminal (but not a `bash` subshell started from `sh`). I haven't made any changes to .profile/.bashrc and don't have .bash_profile or .bash_login, either.

Comment: @jimmij same result.

Comment: Adding something like `nano` to .bash_history does allow it to show up in command history, too, if that helps at all.

Comment: Key bindings have no effect in a script, so testing with a script is useless. If `bash --norc` has the problem, then the culprit is `~/.inputrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this problem occurs on different terminal types, and occurs at a command prompt but not when some other program is reading from the terminal, this is a configuration problem in your shell. You've accidentally defined bindings for `a` and `c`.

Assuming that your shell is bash (the default interactive shell on Ubuntu), check the two relevant configuration files in your home directory:

- `.inputrc`, the configuration file for the readline library, which bash uses. Look for a line starting with `a` and a line starting with `c`.
- `.bashrc`, the configuration file for bash when it runs interactively. Look for a line containing `bind a…` and a line containing `bind c…`.

Comment: There aren't any lines like that in either `.bashrc` or `.inputrc`.

Comment: Ah, but it was an `.inputrc` issue after all. I forgot to put `set` before some variable assignments. Silly me.